# Can not SELECT the Type of a column

Tags: types, casting, teradata

I have the following code:

```
SEL TOP 10 TYPE(prod_id) FROM db.tablename
```

which produces:

> SELECT Failed [5355] The arguments of the CAST function must be of the
>   same character data type.

This is somehow odd.
In am investigating into this because a `join on db.tablename.prod_id` with an other `prod_id` which is `BIGINT` produces

> [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The arguments of
>   the CAST function must be of the same character data type.

using `pyodbc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will be answer for your problem:

SELECT * FROM DBC.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMNNAME='prod_id'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM DBC.COLUMNS
```

will give you all the details about the columns of table as all the teradata tables are stored in DBC schema.